# "Drupal Planet" versus "Planet Drupal"

Tags: word-choice, word-order

Between *Drupal Planet*, and *Planet Drupal*, which one is correct?
I would think *Planet Drupal* is correct, in the same way *Planet Earth* is correct. Which one would be the interpretation of *Drupal Planet*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Planet Drupal* tells me this is a planet that is definitely named *Drupal*.

*Drupal Planet* tells me this is a planet that has *Drupal* as a central feature of the planet in some way, but that *Drupal* isn't necessarily the name of the planet.  Earth could, for example, be considered "the human planet" or "the water planet" by outsiders.

With this distinction in mind, if you wanted to name a website either *Planet Drupal* or *Drupal Planet*, both would be compatible with the idea of "a whole lot of Drupal stuff going on here!"

Comment: _Drupal Planet_ is actually the name of a feed used on drupal.org; in some places of the site it is referenced as _Drupal Planet_, and in other places it is referenced as _Planet Drupal_. From your explanation, it should be named _Drupal Planet_; did I get it right?

Comment: *Planet Drupal* also sounds like *Planet Hollywood*.